React-Redux could not find Redux context value when using useSelector
I created a store and authreducer and every thing works as expected
but when I add the useSelector in app.js I get this error:

ERROR  Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure
the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

(I have tried using useSelector in other files without any errors. )

import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Navigation from "./navigation";
import Navigation2 from "./navigation2";
import { store } from "./src/Redux/store";
import InMemoryCacheFct from "./src/apolloClient/InMemoryCache";

export default function App() {
  // the err is when I add this line even he works in other files
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: ".......serverUrl",
    cache: InMemoryCacheFct(),
    queryDeduplication: true,
  });

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        {user ? <Navigation /> : <Navigation2 />}
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}


You can't use useSelector unless you're inside a component that is below the redux provider in the tree.
You can do this:
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Navigation from "./navigation";
import Navigation2 from "./navigation2";
import { store } from "./src/Redux/store";
import InMemoryCacheFct from "./src/apolloClient/InMemoryCache";

export default function App() {

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: ".......serverUrl",
    cache: InMemoryCacheFct(),
    queryDeduplication: true,
  });

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

function Root() {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  return user ? <Navigation /> : <Navigation2 />
}

You can read up on react context here
